# Routing a form for a polymorphic model's non polymorphic side

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have set up a polymorphic association between Event, Meeting, and TaskList such that:

- An Event can have many TaskLists, A TaskList can belong to one Event.
- A Meeting can have many TaskLists, A TaskList can belong to one Meeting.

**This works and I can create task_lists from the view of these models. However my problem is that I want to be able to add TaskItem to each TaskList such that:**

- A TaskList can have many TaskItems, A TaskItem can belong to one TaskList.

I'm having trouble routing the form for the creation of a task item. I've created a "_form.html.erb" for this and am rendering it from the view of the task_item. I'm using the form below for this, at the moment from the events view, which shows the form fine but throws the routing error "**No route matches [POST] "/events/3/task_lists/new.3**" when clicked on submit.

_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for TaskItem.new, url: new_polymorphic_path([@listable, @task_list, @task_item]) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :content %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :content %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I have also tried setting it up like below which doen't even show the form throwing the error "**First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty**"

```
<%= form_for @task_item do %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :content %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :content %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Models

```
class TaskList 
    belongs_to :listable, polymorphic: true
    has_many :task_items
end

class TaskItem 
    belongs_to :task_list
end

class Event
    has_many :task_lists, as: :listable
end

class Meeting
    has_many :task_lists, as: :listable
end
```

Routes (added :show to task_lists, only: , as my link wouldnt work otherwise.)

```
  concern :has_task_lists do
    resources :task_lists, only: [:new, :index, :create, :show]
  end

  resources :events, :meetings, concerns: [:has_task_lists]

  resources :task_lists, except: [:new, :index, :create] do
    resources :task_items
  end
```

task_items_controller (want it to redirect to the page item was created from, which is the show view for task_list)

```
def create
  @task_item = @task_list.task_items.new(task_item_params)
  if @task_item.save
    redirect_to @task_list, notice: "Task Item Created"
  else
    render :new
  end
```

end

task_lists_controller

```
before_action :load_listable

def show
    @task_list = @listable.task_lists.find(params[:id])
end

def load_listable
    klass = [Event, Meeting].detect { |c| params["#{c.name.underscore}_id"]}
    @listable = klass.find(params["#{klass.name.underscore}_id"])
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the key issues here is that `task_items` are nested a level too deep.

> Rule of thumb: resources should never be nested more than 1 level
>   deep. A collection may need to be scoped by its parent, but a specific
>   member can always be accessed directly by an id, and shouldn’t need
>   scoping.
>   - [Jamis Buck](http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2007/2/5/nesting-resources)

So to untangle this we would declare the routes like so:

```
concern :has_task_lists do
  resources :task_lists, only: [:new, :index, :create]
end

resources :events, :meetings, concerns: [:has_task_lists]

resources :task_lists, except: [:new, :index, :create] do
  resources :task_items
end
```

The [routing concern](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#routing-concerns) lets us re-use the nested routes.

Since we have gotten rid of the extra "parent" we can simplify the form:

```
form_for([ @task_list, @task_item || @task_list.task_items.new ])
```

`@task_item || @task_list.task_items.new` will prevent errors if you embed the form in another controller / action.

### Added

You actually have to create the resource scoped to the parent. Just doing `form_for([@a, @b])` does not automatically associate the records - it just generates the url and sets the form method (POST or PATCH).

```
class TaskItemsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :set_task_list

  def new
    @task_item = @task_list.task_items.new
  end


  def create
    @task_item = @task_list.task_items.new(task_item_params)

    if @task_item.save
      redirect_to task_list_path(@task_list), notice: "Task Item Created"
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

    def set_task_list
       @task_list = TaskList.find(params[:task_list_id])
    end

    # ...

end
```

When you call `@task_list.task_items.new` you are calling the `.new` method on the collection - so the new TaskItem will have the `task_list_id` column set.

Note that you can also write `redirect_to @task_list` and rails will figure the rest out. If you need to redirect to a nested resource such as the newly created item you would do:

```
redirect_to [@task_list, @task_item]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Max, I've changed the routes based on what you said and updated my question with the new routes. However the submit button now throws the error  "ActionController::UrlGenerationError in TaskItemsController#create", with the message "No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"task_lists", :task_list_id=>"12"} missing required keys: [:id]". I've checked the database and it has created the entry into the database but the task_list_id column is null. Also put my code for the relevant controller action. Thanks so much.

Comment: I added an explanation why your records are not being linked.

Comment: I was actually just doing this change myself, now the record gets created fine but I'm still getting an error "NoMethodError in TaskListsController#show" with message "undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass". Updated TaskLists Controller with the load_listable method that the error ponts to.

Comment: Ok, at this point your original question has been answered. Its better that you use this as the starting point for a new question unless you can resolve the issue yourself.